# Microsoft Graph: How to receive list of remote items for drive?

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

How can I quickly receive list of drive items that are [remote items](https://dev.onedrive.com/facets/remoteitem_facet.htm) (items that are links to items on other drives, shared with me items) ?

Of course I can to do something like it:

```
// Universal version
var res = new List<DriveItem>();
var list = await Client.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
while (list != null)
{
    res.AddRange(list.CurrentPage.Where(i => (i.RemoteItem != null)));
    list = (list.NextPageRequest != null) ? (await list.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()) : null;
}
return res;
```

But it too slow, and requires parse all items. Can I use filter to resolve this task? In other words, will code below work on all types of drives (OneDrive Personal, Business, SharePoint ...)?

```
// Filtered version
var res = new List<DriveItem>();
var list = await Client.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().Filter("remoteItem ne null").GetAsync();
while (list != null)
{
    res.AddRange(list.CurrentPage);
    list = (list.NextPageRequest != null) ? (await list.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()) : null;
}
return res;
```

According to OneDrive [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/filtering.htm):

> While the **filter** syntax can be used on *any property* of an item, we have optimized certain properties to be fast and efficient to filter on.
>
> **Note**: In OneDrive for Business, SharePoint Online and SharePoint Server 2016, filtering support only **name** and **url** properties.

Does it mean that OneDrive for Business and SharePoint aren't support filtering by **remoteItem** facet?

Unfortunately Microsoft Grap [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters#filter) doesn't contain any additional information about it.

P.S.: I don't have OneDrive Business account, so, sorry can't check my assumption.

Comment: before to set "-1", please add comment with your opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should join the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram). This program includes a free Office 365 Developer license which will resolve your OneDrive for Business issue. There are several subtle differences between the two systems so testing against both is highly advised.

As to your question, I would take a look at the [sharedWithMe](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/shared_with_me.htm) endpoint. This method returns a collection of items that have been shared with you from remote drives.

I would also highly recommend pivoting to [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph). It provides the same APIs as OneDrive but exposes a vast array of additional endpoints as well. A huge amount of effort is being funneled into Graph, making it a far better long-term strategy.

Comment: Thank you Mark for answer. It's very interesting. But `sharedWithMe` endpoint returns list of all items that shared with me: that are mapped to my drive and not. But I want to receive list of only items that are mapped to root of my drive. With sharedWithMe's list I can't separate such information because all items have `id`, `remotItem` facet and `shared` facet. No any specific information that would say me - this item exists in your root folder as link to shared file and this item are not mapped to your root.
P.S.: I prefer to use Microsoft Graph SDK, no pure OneDrive SDK.

Comment: I understand. OneDrive for Business doesn't support the "Add to my OneDrive" feature that you see in OneDrive. Items are either in your drive or shared with you.